# read files from current date minus 90 days in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading all one by one files which is stored in a directory structure as `YY=18/MM=12/DD=10` and need to read only `current date minus 60 days`. Files will be created created for every day and possibility is also that some day files wont create. so, for that day folder will not create.

I am reading all files which is stored in a directory structure as `YY/MM/DD`.
I am writing below code but its not working.

```
 var datecalculate = {
 var days = 0
 do{
 val start = DateTime.now

 var start1 = DateTime.now.minusDays(days)
 days = days + 1
 var start2 = start1.toString
 datecalculatenow(start2) }

while (days <= 90) 
}    



def datecalculatenow(start2:String):String={
var YY:String = start2.toString.substring(0,4)

var MM:String = start2.toString.substring(5,7)

var DD:String = start2.toString.substring(8,10)

 var datepath = "YYYY=" + YY +"/MM=" +MM +"/DD=" +DD
 var datepath1 = datepath.toString

 org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.read.option("delimiter","|").
 option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").
 csv("/Table/Files" + datepath1  )
 }
```

I expect to read every files from current date minus 60 days, which has directory structure as `YY/MM/DD`

Comment: what operations you do after reading all the files?..because if we have inferSchema true, then it will have headers when you combine them later..

Comment: @stack0114106 Thanks a lot. It will be great help if you can help in above problem.

Comment: @RaviAnandVicky did you know that **Spark** has [_Partition Discovery_](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery), if you just read the base path providing a **schema** and then do a filter for date it should work and only read the files you want.

Answer (score 0):

With spark sql you can use the following in a select statement to subtract 90 days;

```
date_sub(CAST(current_timestamp() as DATE), 90)
```

Comment: I stuked in iterating to every files, Getting minus 90 days in not problem.

Answer (score 0):

As it's possible to generate a dataframe from a list of path , why are you not first generating list of path. Here is the simple and concise way to read data from multiple paths:

```
val paths = (0 until 90).map(days => {
  val tmpDate = DateTime.now.minusDays(days).toString()
  val year = tmpDate.substring(0,4)
  val month = tmpDate.substring(5,7)
  val opdate = tmpDate.toString.substring(8,10)
  (s"basepath/YY=$year/MM=$month/DD=$opdate")
}).toList

val df = spark.read.
        option("delimiter", "|").
        option("header", "true").
        option("inferSchema","true")
        .csv(paths:_*)
```

While generating `paths`, you can filter out the paths that do not exist. I've used some of your codes with some modifications. I've not tested in my local setup but the idea is same. Hopefully it'll help you.